# How to let user enter an integer and start timer based off on that value

Tags: c#, timer

I am in the process of creating my first c# project, a personal time tracking application. Pretty basic so far however before I get any further I would like to have the timer working properly.

So far the timer will start / stop and reset. However a curious thing that I wanted to be able to do was for the user to set a time and have the counter start from there.

So if they wanted to start at 20 minutes and have it count up, then it would

example: 00:20:00 would count from 20 and add to it.

However so far I have not figured it out.

Here is the code:

```
namespace TimeTracker
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      TimerBox.Text = string.Format("00:00:00");
    }

    int ss = 0;
    public void StartButton_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      timer1.Start();
      timer1.Enabled = true;
      timer1.Interval = 1000;
    }
    public void StopButton_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      timer1.Stop();
      TimerBox.Text = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(ss).ToString(); 
    }
    public void ResetButton_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      ss = 0;
      TimerBox.Text = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(ss).ToString();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      ss++;
      TimerBox.Text = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(ss).ToString(); 
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the application:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wquBP.jpg

Any help would be appreciated, I can provide more details if you would like!

EDIT: Since it was unclear, my question is:

What process would be better for coding this, adding to the integer or if there is a better way of implementing this?

Comment: Do you have an actual question or is this just a request for someone to code this feature for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the initial value of that `ss` variable to any predefined integer entered by user, e.g.

```
DateTime _dt = DateTime.Parse(TimertBox.Text);
int ss = _dt.Second + _dt.Minute * 60 + _dt.Hour * 3600;
```

Comment: so do a check for a user input on the start click and if it is not = default value then begin the timer from that new integer?

Comment: Yes this worked! I spent so much time trying to get this right it was redic. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like...

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private TimeSpan Offset = new TimeSpan();
    private System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch SW = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer1.Interval = 1000;
        UpdateTime();
    }

    public void StartButton_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TimeSpan TS;
        if (TimeSpan.TryParse(TimerBox.Text, out TS))
        {
            Offset = TS;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Starting Time. Resetting to Zero");
            Offset = new TimeSpan();
        }

        SW.Restart();
        UpdateTime();
        timer1.Start();
    }

    public void StopButton_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SW.Stop();
        timer1.Stop();
    }

    public void ResetButton_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Offset = new TimeSpan();
        if (SW.IsRunning)
        {
            SW.Restart();
        }
        else
        {
            SW.Reset();
        }
        UpdateTime();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateTime();   
    }

    private void UpdateTime()
    {
        TimerBox.Text = Offset.Add(SW.Elapsed).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the timer normally (from 00:00:00.00), and when updating your output label / textbox / etc. just add the time the user has written.